# What technologies is Microsoft Visual Studio IDE built on?

Tags: visual-studio

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) page's "Architecture" part it looks like it's more of a conglomerate of different services so I'm guessing lots of different programming languages went into writing Microsoft Visual Studio.
But out of curiosity (unlike VSCode, I can't find this information anywhere) what programming language(s) and framework are used in writing Visual Studio?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-Visual-Studio-essentially-a-Windows-Forms-WPF-application

Comment: There isn't much about Visual Studio that makes it an IDE, it is first and foremost a plugin framework.  Written in C++ and supporting COM to allow Microsoft and anybody else to implement an IDE for a language.  They used to make it available with the "Shell edition" to allow anybody to create their own IDE from scratch, now discontinued.  That was added to over the years, a lot of those plugins are now written in .NET with MEF to make it easier.  The Quora post is nonsense, lots of Winforms code is still present.

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to have any links where I could read up further?